# Cannot issue identity to participant using hyperldeger composer

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I have defined Participant as :

participant SupplierChainParticipant  identified by participantId {

```
o String participantId

o String identity

o String type

o String secret
```

}

I have also created participant using composer-rest-sever loopback API, Participant created :

{

```
"$class": "org.suppchain.SupplierChainParticipant",

"participantId": "Deepak",

"identityName": "Parmar",

"type": "OEM",

"secret": "not defined"
```

}

Now, I am trying to issue identity using composer cli using command :

composer identity issue -n 'supplychain-network' -p hlfv1 -i admin -s adminpw -u dvparmar -a "org.suppchain.SupplierChainParticipant#Deepak"

But, I am getting following error:

Error: fabric-ca request register failed with errors [[{"code":0,"message":"User 'dvparmar' is already registered"}]]
Command failed.

Any input/suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: The error means that the CA has already issues a cert for this userId - you need to pick another one.

Comment: True, but I had only created participant and haven't issued identity. then how come CA is giving error that user is already registered? 

If user is already registered, then how can i get secret for the registered user then?

Comment: I tried to register "dvparmar" earlier, but command was not successful and got error because of providing wrong namespace. I would like to understand if user "dvparmar" has never received identity in past, then how come CA is throwing error that user is already register.

Comment: Perhaps the issuing of the cert succeeded, but the mapping of the cert to a Composer participant failed (because the participant does not exist)?

Comment: I think that It should first check whether participant does exist or not, then issue Certificate, What's your view?

Comment: Yes, this may be a bug. If you can reproduce it please create an issue here: https://github.com/hyperledger/composer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please file an issue if you can reproduce this and we will look at the order in which we perform operations and the error handling.